# PostMessage only works once?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to send a message from a global WindowProc function to a GUI class.
The message is defined as follows:

```
#define WM_ENV_RESIZED (WM_APP + 0)
```

My WindowProc function looks like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int res;
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            std::cout << "window resized" << std::endl;

            res = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_ENV_RESIZED, 0, 0);
            if ( res == 0 )    //<-- res is never 0
            {
                std::cout << "PostMessage failure!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The message is then received in the GUI class like so:

```
MSG msg;
while (running)
{
    while ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
        processWindowsMessage(&msg);

    //DirectX render calls
}
```

Now my problem is that the message is never received by PeekMessage(). It is only received once when the window is created. After that is it never received.

Calling GetLastError() directly after PostMessage() always returns error code 6, which stands for ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But this doesn't make any sense, because PostMessage() never returns 0, which means something went wrong during posting.
I have tried bypassing the message queue and using SendMessage() to send the message directly to the window, but that always returns 0 (with the same error code 6..).

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. How can I make sure a posted message is always received when using PeekMessage()?

**EDIT:**
I've updated the message loop as Remy suggested. Below is the code in processWindowsMessage()

```
void Environment::processWindowsMessage( MSG *msg )
{
    switch ( msg->message )
    {
        case WM_ENV_RESIZED:
            std::cout << "WM_ENV_RESIZED caught" << std::endl;
            break;
        case WM_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        default:
            TranslateMessage(msg);
            DispatchMessage(msg);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `PostMessage` says it succeeded, then it succeeded. Calling `GetLastError` is useless in that situation because the error code is only defined on failure. Some API functions set the error code prospectively, *in case* there's an error. Do not call `GetLastError` unless the documentation advised you to. The documentation typically only advises it on failure. Reasons to call it on success are rare.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your processWindowsMessage function?

Comment: The window handle used in the PostMessage call makes no sense.  It certainly shouldn't be hWnd.

Comment: @HansPassant: why do you think `hWnd` should not be used? If he wants his custom message to be posted to the same window that is being resized, then it is valid to post to `hWnd`. And maybe he really wants his custom message to go through the message queue and not directly in the WindowProc.  I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. Remy is right. I want to process the window resized message outside of the WindowProc. This is because I need to resize some DirectX buffers, which is handled in the GUI class

Comment: What is the "Environment" class, if it has a window, you can post the WM_ENV_RESIZED message directly to it rather than to the original windows. And how is this "Environment" window created, is it by the main thread or a another thread ? If it created by another thread, you may want to look into the PostThreadMessage api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your message is being posted to the same window that is being resized, `DispatchMessage()` will send the message to the window's procedure like any other message targetting that window.  So either:

1) process the message inside of `windowProcedure()`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            std::cout << "window resized" << std::endl;

            if (!PostMessage(hWnd, WM_ENV_RESIZED, 0, 0))
            {
                std::cout << "PostMessage failure!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;

        case WM_ENV_RESIZED:
            std::cout << "env resized" << std::endl;
            //...
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

.

```
MSG msg;
while (running)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //DirectX render calls
}
```

2) if you do not want to process custom messages in your window procedure, then change your message loop to move the `TranslateMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()` calls into `processWindowsMessage()` and only call them for non-custom messages, do not translate/dispatch custom messages:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            std::cout << "window resized" << std::endl;

            if (!PostMessage(hWnd, WM_ENV_RESIZED, 0, 0))
            {
                std::cout << "PostMessage failure!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

.

```
MSG msg;
while (running)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        processWindowsMessage(&msg);

    //DirectX render calls
}
```

.

```
void processWindowsMessage(MSG *msg)
{
    switch (msg->message)
    {
        case WM_ENV_RESIZED:
            std::cout << "env resized" << std::endl;
            //...
            break;

        default:
            TranslateMessage(msg);
            DispatchMessage(msg);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good advice in general. I wanted to say that it doesn't address the OP's concerns but honestly he's off in the weeds so far that these are excellent tips.

Comment: Given the original code shown, the only way I could see it not working is if `TranslateMessage()` were modifying the `MSG` into something else that `processWindowsMessage()` did not recognize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Remy. I've modified my code as you suggested, but the message is still not caught. I did notice though, that if I put a break on the switch in processWindowsMessage(), wait a bit and then continue running the code, the message is received and processed. This is rather curious behavior and I'm not sure why this is happening...

Comment: I will set this as the answer for the time being. If I later find out what was wrong I will post it here. Thanks for all the replies ;)